# .NET regular expression find the number and group the number

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a question about .NET regular expressions.

Now I have several strings in a list, there may be a number in the string, and the rest part of string is same, just like

```
string[] strings = {"var1", "var2", "var3", "array[0]", "array[1]", "array[2]"}
```

I want the result is `{"var$i" , "array[$i]"}`, and I have a record of the number which record the number matched, like a dictionary

```
var$i {1,2,3} & 
array[$i] {0, 1 ,2}
```

I defined a regex like this

```
var numberReg = new Regex(@".*(<number>\d+).*");
foreach(string str in strings){
  var matchResult = numberReg.Match(name);
  if(matchResult.success){
    var number = matchResult.Groups["number"].ToString();
    //blablabla
```

But the regex here seems to be not work(never match success), I am new at regex, and I want to solve this problem ASAP.

Comment: BTW, there is no such thing as a C# regular expression. C# is the programming language. The framework is .NET, which has regular expressions.

Comment: You should take a look at the 'Regulator' its a great tool for learning how to write regular expressions as well as makes it easier to create your expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your regex:

```
(?<number>\d+)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what exactly you want. However looking into your code, I assume you have to somehow extract the numbers (and maybe variable names) from your list of values. Try this:

```
// values
string[] myStrings = { "var1", "var2", "var3", "array[0]", "array[1]", "array[2]" };

// matches
Regex x = new Regex(@"(?<pre>\w*)(?<number>\d+)(?<post>\w*)");
MatchCollection matches = x.Matches(String.Join(",", myStrings));

// get the numbers
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    string number = m.Groups["number"].Value;                
    ...
}
```